# boost::interprocess message queue Race Condition on creation?

Tags: c++, boost, message-queue, race-condition, interprocess

I am trying to debug sporadic access violations that occur inside a boost::interprocess message queue. (access violation reading an address in the shared memory region).

Environment: boost 1.54, VC++2010. Occurs in both Debug & Release builds.

It always occurs on or about line 854 (in case of reception) in message_queue.hpp:
Comments were added by me

```
      recvd_size     = top_msg.len; // top_msg points to invalid location
```

Or line 756 (in case of sending)

```
BOOST_ASSERT(free_msg_hdr.priority == 0); // free_msg_hdr points to invalid location
```

It appears as though this is related to the message queue creation. If a message queue is created "properly" (i.e. without the possible race condition), the error never occurs.
Otherwise it might occur on timed_receive() or timed_send() on the queue at seemingly random times.

I came up with a short example that represents the problem:
Unfortunately I cannot run it on Coliru, since it requires two processes.
One has to be started without any parameters, the second with any single parameter.
After a number of runs, one of the processes will crash in message_queue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/interprocess/ipc/message_queue.hpp>
#include <boost/thread.hpp>
#include <boost/assert.hpp>
#include <boost/date_time.hpp>

using namespace boost::interprocess;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using boost::posix_time::microsec_clock; // microsec_clock is ambiguous between boost::posix_time and boost::interprocess. What are the odds?

int main(int argc, wchar_t** argv)
{
    while(true)
    {
        int proc = 0;
        message_queue* queues[2] = {NULL, NULL};
        std::string names[] = {"msgq0", "msgq1"};
        if(1 == argc)
        {
            proc = 0;
            message_queue::remove(names[0].c_str());
            if(NULL != queues[0]) { delete queues[0]; queues[0] = NULL; }
            queues[0] = new message_queue(open_or_create, names[0].c_str(), 128, 10240);

            bool bRet = false;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    if(NULL != queues[1]) { delete queues[1]; queues[1] = NULL; }
                    queues[1]=new message_queue(open_only, names[1].c_str());
                    bRet = true;
                }
                catch(const interprocess_exception&)
                {
                    //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2));
                    delete queues[1];
                    queues[1] = NULL; 
                    continue;
                }
            }while(!bRet);

        }
        else
        {
            proc = 1;
            message_queue::remove(names[1].c_str());
            if(NULL != queues[1]) { delete queues[1]; queues[1] = NULL; }
            queues[1] = new message_queue(open_or_create, names[1].c_str(), 128, 10240);

            bool bRet = false;
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    if(NULL != queues[0]) { delete queues[0]; queues[0] = NULL; }
                    queues[0]=new message_queue(open_only, names[0].c_str());
                    bRet = true;
                }
                catch(const interprocess_exception&)
                {
                    //boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(2));
                    delete queues[0];
                    queues[0] = NULL;
                    continue;
                }
            }while(!bRet);
        }

        long long nCnt = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 1; ++i)
        {
            if(proc)
            {
                std::string sOut;
                sOut = "Proc1 says: Hello ProcA " + std::to_string(nCnt) + " ";
                sOut.resize(10230, ':');
                for(int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
                {
                    queues[1]->timed_send(sOut.data(), sOut.size(), 0, ptime(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()) + milliseconds(1));
                }

                bool bMessage = false;
                for(int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
                {
                    size_t nRec; unsigned int nPrio;
                    std::string sIn; sIn.resize(10240);
                    bMessage = queues[0]->timed_receive(&sIn[0], 10240, nRec, nPrio, ptime(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()) + milliseconds(1));
                    if(bMessage)
                    {
                        sIn.resize(nRec);
                        //std::cout << sIn << " ";
                    }
                }
                if(bMessage)
                {
                    //std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                std::string sOut;
                sOut = "Proc0 says: Hello Procccccccdadae4325a " + std::to_string(nCnt);
                sOut.resize(10240, '.');
                for(int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
                {
                    queues[0]->timed_send(sOut.data(), sOut.size(), 0, ptime(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()) + milliseconds(1));
                }

                bool bMessage = false;
                for(int n = 0; n < 3; ++n)
                {
                    size_t nRec; unsigned int nPrio;
                    std::string sIn; sIn.resize(10240);
                    bMessage = queues[1]->timed_receive(&sIn[0], 10240, nRec, nPrio, ptime(boost::posix_time::microsec_clock::universal_time()) + milliseconds(1));
                    if(bMessage)
                    {
                        sIn.resize(nRec);
                        //std::cout << sIn << " ";
                    }
                }
                if(bMessage)
                {
                    //std::cout << std::endl;
                }
            }

            nCnt++;
            boost::this_thread::sleep(boost::posix_time::milliseconds(10));
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am still thinking I might be doing something wrong, since I cannot find anything about this problem anywhere else, and the boost libraries are normally very good.

Is there anything I might be doing wrong with the usage of the message_queue in this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that **both** processes using `open_or_create` is a supported idiom. Are you aware of [this thread on the mailing list](http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Interprocess-hang-locking-p-hdr-gt-m-mutex-td3756339.html)? I can't find more discussions so it looks to me like lifetime management wasn't eventually considered necessary to add.

Thus you'll need to synchronise the creation manually with `boost::interprocess` or possibly by having one of the processes retrying to `open_only` the queue until the other process creates it.

Comment: Thanks! That's what the example is doing. Each process creates the outgoing queue (open_or_create) and spins on the the other with open_only, as you suggested. However, just due to a hunch from your post and the link, I tried with create_only instead of open_or_create. I'm currently testing this, I'll get back in a bit.

Comment: Ok, after some quick testing, create_only, together with a sleep(1000) in the catch block for the open_only seems to mitigate the issue to a point where it doesn't happen in the production application. However, in the test application I can still reproduce it, albeit much less frequently. So there seems to be a race on creation/opening a message queue that needs to be worked around. I find it astounding that this has apparently never come up anywhere, although the discussion about the locks used makes me feel a little bit queasy about its use.

Comment: I may look around for other IPC queue libraries should this happen again, but for now the above mentioned "solution" appears to produce acceptable results, at least in the production application. I'll link this post on the boost bugtracker; maybe someone has some input there.